# How to enable Street View in GeoDjango

Tags: django, geodjango

I am using the Django's [**`PointField(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#pointfield) in my model as

```
# models.py
from django.contrib.gis.db import models


class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    point = models.PointField()
```

Then, I configured the `admin.py` as normal,

```
from django.contrib import admin


class LocationModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("id", "name",)
    list_display_links = ("id", "name",)


admin.site.register(Location, LocationModelAdmin)
```

But, when I am trying to add the entry via Django Admin, I am getting the ***areal view*** of the map

[image: areal view]

**Q: How can I change this areal view to a street-view?**

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the built-in [**`OSMGeoAdmin`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#osmgeoadmin) admin class which will give the street-view in Django Admin.

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib.gis import admin as geo_admin


class LocationModelAdmin(geo_admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
    list_display = ("id", "name",)
    list_display_links = ("id", "name",)
```